# Calling external API from Android app in emulator

Tags: android, api, react-native, android-emulator

I am trying to make external calls to an API hosted on Digital Ocean (DG), from a React-Native (Android app) running on the emulator on my computer. By monitoring the logs in the terminal on DG, I can see that the requests are successfully sent, since the backend logs HTTP 200 response. However, whenever doing an API request, an alert box is displayed with some text, see attached image.

I'm not sure what the error message is saying or where the problem lays?

**Alert box on Android emulator when sending requests to external API**

[image: Alert box on Android emulator when sending requests to external API]

Comment: Please attach some code. Otherwise it could be million things. Also the error message is not clear. Better log the message with console.error(error) so you have more information.

Comment: I fully understand, I'm just not sure what code to include that would be relevant. I wouldn't want to just copy paste endless code just because...

Comment: post the code containing api request